# While Loop not Working termination issue

Tags: c++

so basically the user enters type of wood Which can be P F C M O If the user enters 'T' the loop is supposed to terminate and output the total the code I Have so far is supposed to this but its not working.In the cout i have not written the code to output the total but its just a test to see if i get output and i in the void function i get the input from the user which could be for example P 10 10 10 10 if its just T the loop should terminate and cout what ever i had.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void get_user_input(char&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
float compute_item_cost(char, int, int, int, int);
const float pine_cost = 0.89;
const float fir_cost = 1.09;
const float cedar_cost = 2.26;
const float maple_cost = 4.50;
const float oak_cost = 3.10;
int main()
{
    int quanity, height, width, length;
    string name_of_wood;
    char type;//declare variables
    get_user_input(type, quanity, height, width, length);


    do
    {
        get_user_input(type, quanity, height, width, length);


    } while (type!='T');


    cout << "33333333333333333333333333333333333e";
    return 0;

}
void get_user_input(char& type, int& quanity, int& height, int& width, int& length)
{
    cout << "Enter the wood type";
    cin >> type >> quanity >> height >> width >> length;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void get_user_input(char& type, int& quanity, int& height, int& width, int& length)
{
    cin >> type;
    if (type == 'T') return;
    cin >> quanity >> height >> width >> length;
}
```

The reason it's not working is because it's waiting for you to input all five values before the cin statement finishes.